# Work done by spring when compressed by a ball

Tags: work

Let us asssume a vertical spring is fixed on ceiling. A ball has been thrown upward and it compresses the spring. What should be the work done by spring in this case?

My understanding is using work energy theorem. Let $v$ be the velocity of the ball when it is just about to hit the spring and let the spring be compressed by $x$. Evoking work energy theorem,we get $W_{\mathrm{spring}}+W_{\mathrm{gravity}}=-\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ and if mass is $m$,the equation becomes $W_{\mathrm{spring}}=\frac{1}{2}mv^2-mgx$. But according to a book,the answer was just given by $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$. I don't understand why that's the case. Is there any flaw in my understanding? If so,please enlighten me.

Comment: I think you are correct. Most likely the question intended to ignore the effect of gravity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not clear enough as to whether or not to include the gravitational force but even then I think that the book answer is incorrect.
Consider the **system as the ball alone**, then there are two external forces acting on the ball; the downward force due to the spring and the downward force due to the gravitational attraction of the Earth, magnitude $mg$.
The work done by the gravitational force is $-mgx$ (negative because force is downwards and displacement is upwards).
Let the work done by the spring (on the ball) be $W_{\rm spring}$ and the change in the kinetic energy of the ball is $0-\frac 12 mv^2 = -\frac 12 mv^2$.

Applying the work-energy theorem gives $W_{\rm spring}+(-mgx) = -\frac 12mv^2\Rightarrow W_{\rm spring}=+mgx-\frac 12mv^2$

Note the signs of the terms on the right-hand side of the equation.
With no gravitational force the work done by the spring $(-\frac 12 mv^2)$ is negative because the force exerted by the spring  on the ball is downwards and the displacement of the ball is upwards. Put another way work is being done by the ball on the spring.
The positive sign in $+mgx$ might seem strange but what you must remember is that the work done by the spring is negative which means that the ball has done positive work on the spring and increases the elastic potential energy stored in the spring.
So the $+mgx$ term will make the work done by the spring less negative and so the increase in the stored elastic potential energy will be less.